# Can I use a loop to quicky produce x amount of checkbuttons?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

Is it possible to iterate the production of 3 checkbuttons in TkInter. For instance I seperatly create my 3 buttons below, but can I simplify this code by running a loop, if BtnLst is defined as so.

```
    BtnLst = ["Power", "Temperature", "Sunlight"]
    #####Loop here?
```

...

```
    C1 = Checkbutton(frame, text = "Power",\
             onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0, height=1, \
             width = 10)
    C1.pack(side=LEFT)
    C2 = Checkbutton(frame, text = "Temperature",\
             onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0, height=1, \
             width = 10)
    C2.pack(side=LEFT,padx =5, ipadx=12)
    C3 = Checkbutton(frame, text = "Sunlight",\
             onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0, height=1, \
             width = 10)
    C3.pack(side=LEFT)
```

Is this even possible in tkinter because I have defined all 3 buttons separately?

Comment: Please read http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure, it's simple.

```
for name in BtnLst:
    button = Checkbutton(frame, text=name, onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0, height=1, width = 10)
    button.pack(side=LEFT)
```

---

If each element has its own unique text, configuration options, and callback functions, you can still create them in a list, but you need to hold each of these things in a collection while you iterate. I don't recomend doing this if you only have three buttons; since you're making three lists, you're not really gaining anything complexity wise. It might still be worth doing if you have, say, 30 buttons or something.

```
names = ["Power", "Temperature", "Sunlight"]
callbacks = [SomeOtherClass.foo, SomeOtherClass.bar, SomeOtherClass.baz]
pack_options = [{}, {"padx": 5, "ipadx":12}, {}]
for name, callback, pack_options in zip(names, callbacks, pack_options):
    button = Checkbutton(frame, text=name, onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0, height=1, width = 10, command=callback)
    button.pack(side=LEFT, **pack_options)
```

Comment: What about the `padx =5, ipadx=12`

Comment: I don't think that matters here actually. It wouldn't make much sense if only one button has those attributes.

Comment: @TidB The reason I specified the middle padding was because of the length x of the word 'temperature' as it was wrapping around in the button. following this method, how can I still make sure it doesn't wrap and displays all on one line?

Comment: I don't suppose you could specify `padx=5, ipadx=12` for every button, regardless of whether they would otherwise wrap?

Comment: @Kevin Not really as I would still like the actual checkboxes to be close to the corresponding text

Comment: With this method how can I still specify 3 specific commands for each check button?

Comment: executing functions that are in another class

Answer (score 1):

Use a list comprehension to create a list of buttons:

```
C = [Checkbutton(frame, text=x, onvalue=1, offvalue=0, height=1, width = 10)
      for x in BtnList]
```

Then pack them as necessary.

```
C[0].pack(side=LEFT)
C[1].pack(side=LEFT, padx=5, ipadx=12)
C[2].pack(side=LEFT)
```